# Does high atmospheric pressure in the atmosphere push warm air down?

Tags: atmosphere

The BBC ran an article [Extreme weather: What is it and how is it connected to climate change](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-58073295) that contained this graphic:

[image]

Is this accurate? **Does high pressure in the atmosphere push warm air down, which is then compressed and gets even hotter?** From basic knowledge it would seem that "high pressure in the atmosphere" would mean denser air, which would (possibly as bubbles?) displace the less-dense warm air, letting this less-dense warm air "float" on it (perhaps the warm air also moves up through the denser air as bubbles). Details of the lower-warm-air / higher-dense-air interface aside, what really happens? Does the denser air move down and the warmer air move up (as I believe) or does the denser air (called high pressure in the graphic) push the warm air down, as depicted in the graphic?